# Android getevent and sendevent: How to get all available commands and then how to selectively send commands for execution

Tags: android, event-handling, adb, pi

I wish to control an androidtv box via pi using adb. I am able to send KEYCODES and have the android box execute them, however I would like to accomplish this via sendevent for quicker execution and reaction.

1.) how can I get a list of the available commands - I assume that they are in the eventxx files in the android box, however the device is not rooted so I can not access them directly. Is the only way to execute commands while recording the output using getevent?

2.) Once I have a list of the available commands, what is the proper format/spacing to send them to the android box from the pi? I have read that I need to insert a pause for timing reason but I am not clear how/where to do that.

I would appreciate some examples or reference where I may be able to get some additional info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How fast do you need to send events?

Comment: The use case is for controlling the androidTV box via remote, so it would not be more than a hand-full of consecutive commands at a time. Reaction time is not critical but I expect that it would be faster than sending KEYCODES using keyevent which is the objective.